# How to get a rolling forecast by using a loop in R running

Tags: r, loops, forecasting

I'm trying to create an estimation of a return for month 37 by using the date of the last 36 month and keep doing this for 180 times. I.e. for month 38 I'm using data from month 2-37 for month 39 I'm using 3-38 and so on.

What I came up so far with is this:

```
# data point 37 
x_36 <- Data_Question_5$BDI[1:36]
y_36 <- Data_Question_5$`Mkt-RF`[1:36]

alpha_beta_estimate_36 <- lm(y_36~x_36)

alpha_36 <- coef(alpha_beta_estimate_36)[1]
beta_36 <- coef(alpha_beta_estimate_36)[2]
print(alpha_36)
print(beta_36)

return_estimate_37 <- alpha_36 + beta_36*Data_Question_5$BDI[36]

Data_Question_5$rt1[37] <- return_estimate_37
View(Data_Question_5)

# data point 38
x_37 <- Data_Question_5$BDI[(1+1):(36+1)]
y_37 <- Data_Question_5$`Mkt-RF`[(1+1):(36+1)]

alpha_beta_estimate_37 <- lm(y_37~x_37)

alpha_37 <- coef(alpha_beta_estimate_37)[1]
beta_37 <- coef(alpha_beta_estimate_37)[2]

return_estimate_38 <- alpha_37 + beta_37*Data_Question_5$BDI[(36+1)]

Data_Question_5$rt1[(37+1)] <- return_estimate_38
```

I'd like to get this in a loop and have R add +2, +3, all the way up to 180 in order to get 180 different estimates. Not sure how to get this running.

Would appreciate if anyone can help out!

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(i in 0:179)
  { 
   X <- Data_Question_5$BDI[(1+i):(36+i)]
   Y <- Data_Question_5$'Mkt - Rf'[(1+i):(36+i)]
   Xend <- Data_Question_5$BDI[36+i]
   Model <- lm(Y~X)
   Estim <- coef(Model)[1] + coef(Model)[2]*Xend
   Data_Question_5$rt1[37+i] <- Estim
  }
```